# incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8 and debug(params)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, character-encoding

I'm receiving this error whenever I edit an user's information. The localhost tells me that the error occured around this line...

```
<%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
```

Parameters returned...

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"hC/BQTSBodv+qlvhYnxJ4mqMl+w3G1FLwopxpbmsm/g=",
 "user"=>{"name"=>"jason",
 "email"=>"jason1",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "commit"=>"Save changes",
 "id"=>"7"}
```

What's causing this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: What are the params for the request?

Comment: `jason` and `jason1`. The other two fields, which are password and password confirmation are blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Try to recreate your template file from scratch in a UTF-8 friendly editor.
2. Put `config.encoding = "utf-8"` in your application.rb file.
3. Add this code in your environment.rb:

   `Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8`
   `Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8`
4. If you are working with MySql use the "mysql2" gem.
5. Put `# encoding: utf-8` at the top of your file.

Comment: Used Aptana with default UTF-8 encoding and followed through with 1-5 and it's still not working. I'm using postgresql.