# Ruby on Rails with Sql Server (incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sql-server-2008, freetds, unixodbc, tiny-tds

is there any way to assign the string encoding to UTF-8 in Ruby On Rails 3?

Database Server: Windows Server 2008 R2

PC: Debian Squeeze.

I use Sql Server 2008 with ODBC and found (config/**database.yml**):

```
development:
  adapter: sqlserver
  host: 192.168.0.13\SQLDEVELOPMENT
  mode: odbc
  dsn: development
  database: railsDev
  username: developerRails
  password: secret
  encoding: utf8
```

gemfile:

```
...
gem 'tiny_tds'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'
```

freetds.cfg:

```
[global]
        tds version = 4.2

[development]
        host = 192.168.0.13
        port = 3341
        intance = SQLDEVELOPMENT
        tds version = 8.0
```

My problem is this:

`incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT`

`Extracted source (around line #28):`

```
26:     <td><%= machine.id_maq %></td>
27:     <td><%= machine.cod_maq %></td>
28:     <td><%= machine.eqp_maq %></td> <!-- string -->
29:     <td><%= machine.mar_maq %></td>
30:     <td><%= machine.mod_maq %></td>
31:     <td><%= machine.ser_maq %></td>
```

Full trace:

```
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb:135:in `concat'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb:135:in `concat'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/buffers.rb:11:in `<<'
app/views/machines/index.html.erb:28:in `block in _app_views_machines_index_html_erb__522342465_91242820'
app/views/machines/index.html.erb:23:in `each'
app/views/machines/index.html.erb:23:in `_app_views_machines_index_html_erb__522342465_91242820'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:46:in `block in render_template'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `render_with_layout'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:45:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:18:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
/home/fhidalgo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:296:in `realtime'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:196:in `respond_to'
app/controllers/machines_controller.rb:8:in `index'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__557110257__process_action__673728653__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:612:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__680852545__call__737805886__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/home/fhidalgo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/fhidalgo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/fhidalgo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

[This does not help me at all.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317666/incompatible-character-encodings-ascii-8bit-and-utf-8-and-debugparams)

I put this: `28:     <td><%= machine.eqp_maq.force_encoding("UTF-8") %></td>` and works, but I need this throughout the project.

I need to force the strings encoding to UTF-8, is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't use the old 'odbc' connection mode.
When using TinyTds you should use the 'dblib' mode:

```
  development:
    adapter: sqlserver
    mode: dblib
    host: 192.168.0.13\SQLDEVELOPMENT
    database: railsDev
    username: developerRails
    password: secret
```

See also: https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/wiki/Using-TinyTds

Comment: Thanks, but how do I configure dblib? I use 
.odbcinst.ini                                                                          
[FreeTDS]
Description     = TDS driver (Sybase/MS SQL)
Driver          = /usr/lib/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/odbc/libtdsS.so
CPTimeout       =
CPReuse         =
FileUsage       = 1

Comment: Hi, I thought it was more complicated setup, if you had to reinstall freetds.conf, but by the moments work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your views, specially the ones that are going to deploy UFT-8 characters are encoded in UTF-8. I solved a similar problem with MySQL that way

Comment: I use to do that [magic_encoding](https://github.com/m-ryan/magic_encoding).

    cmd<root_project>#magic_encoding
    "Magic comments set for 54 source files"

Comment: I don't know, but  magic_enoding did not change the views. I did try manually and not work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the error as follows:

In **application.html.erb**:

```
<div class="body">
    <%= yield.force_encoding("UTF-8") %>
</div>
```

Not think it is the best solution but it works.